# Compare $_GET variable to array in php

Tags: php

I am getting a variable from the url in php using $_GET[]. The url looks like: http://www.site.com/index.php?x=B%FCergschaften which i am comparing to values in an array: `$y=array('Bauherrenhaftpflicht','Gebäudeversicherung','Büergschaften');`

I understand that the variable in the url is decoded by the $_GET function but when i compare it to the array i am not getting a match.

This is the code i use to compare:

```
$x = $_GET['x']; foreach($y as $value){ if($value == $x){ echo "Found!"; } }
```

I have tried [urldecode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#refsect1-function.urldecode-notes) but it doesn't work.

How do I correctly decode the variable from the url so that the special character is correctly decoded and the variable compared to the array?

Many thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $_GET['x'];`?

Comment: My guess is this has to do with the `ü` character.

Comment: the output of $_GET['x'] is Büergschaften

Comment: Nope, `In_array($key, $array)` or `array_search($key, $value)` instead. The array is searching by values, not by keys. In_array returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and array_search return key of matched element

Comment: Its working with $x=urldecode($_GET['x'])..try again..

Comment: Tried $x=urldecode($_GET['x']) doesn't work.

Comment: What about $x=utf8_encode(urldecode($_GET['x'])) ?

Comment: @Kristian: Very nice, `utf8_encode(urldecode($_GET['x']))` definitely works. `var_dump(in_array(utf8_encode(urldecode("B%FCergschaften")), $y));` prints `bool(true)`. Please post this as answer so that OP can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comments:

```
$x = utf8_encode(urldecode($_GET['x']));
```

And also you should/could use `in_array()`

```
if (in_array($x, $y)) {
echo "Found!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using special characters that are out of the default character set you should either decode the array values or encode the GET param value to UTF-8

I'm testing this locally and it is working for me:

```
$x = utf8_encode(urldecode($_GET['x']));
$y=array('Bauherrenhaftpflicht','Gebäudeversicherung','Büergschaften');

echo in_array($x,$y);  // outputs 1 (true)
```

Let us know if it works for you.